# In Github-flavored Markdown, when a table cell content is long, how can it be broken into multiple source lines?

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

The following produces a three-row table with an empty cell between Topic 1 and Topic 2.

I've tried putting a backslash following Start, and tried eliding the vertical separator on the Continued line.  It seems that there IS no escaping of the end of line (in that the backslash shows up at the end of the line in the output) and that if the following line's vertical separator is missing, then the table is considered finished.

```
First Header  | Second Header
------------- | -------------
Topic 1       | Explanation Start
              | Explanation Continued
Topic 2       | Content Cell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that this isn't possible. Line breaks that occur in tables always generate rows in the rendered content.